# When should I use a boost pedal in a performance?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, performing, guitar-effects, effects-pedal

I recently purchased a boost pedal for my pedalboard, and was wondering, when do I use it? Just during solos? Or in chorus's as well? I would like to know the correct usage of the pedal, any help is appreciated!

Comment: There are no rights and wrongs except for what sounds good to you. Charles gives some good advice in his answer, but any way it improves your sound is a good way. There are a lot of players who have a boost pedal kicked in all the time, e.g. in order to push a tube amp.

Comment: Out of interest, what does the pedal do? Literally just raise the volume ?

Comment: @user2808054 Yes haha that is literally what it does, it is helpful for solos, lead parts, or when you need to just come out in front of everyone else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically you use the boost pedal any time you need an extra bit of volume to stand out. Typically this is during a guitar solo, but yes, sometimes it is also useful in a song's chorus if the whole band picks up the energy a bit. But as with all effects, use your ears as a guide. Obviously you don't want to use it all the time, but for certain moments in a set it can be very effective. Especially with a tube amp, you can get a great dirty-ish tone. I like to set my amp right on the edge of breaking up (on the line between clean and dirty basically), so when I kick in the boost pedal it drives the tubes a bit harder and gets a nice overdriven tone, but I have the option of turning the boost off and playing a bit lighter to keep a mostly clean sound.

It's worth mentioning though, that the use of pedals comes down to personal preference, and every guitarist needs to find their own sound. Experiment a lot, both alone and with the band, and see what kind of sounds you can get out of it.

Comment: Excellent answer! I appreciate it a lot! What about volume, should I have it a lot higher? Like 25% higher volume? Less or more?

Comment: It really depends on context and how you are using it. If you are playing with a band that is the best place to test out the levels to make sure when you boost that your solos are loud enough but not overpowering. Only you and your ears can figure that one out. 25% might be a good place to start.

Comment: Great answer but just want to add one point. Think about the rest of the band. In general don't boost your own volume during a time that the vocalist is performing, or someone else in the band is having a solo moment.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, a boost pedal can also be a great tool when you have multiple pedals running through your pedal-board. It gives an extra "boost" to make up for some signal loss and the "lost flavor" when the signal travels down multiple pedals.